# how the letters and numbers exist in the first place in the CPU?

Tags: binary

how the letters and numbers exist in the first place in the CPU. All u have is binary numbers that not even numbers it's more like 'on/off' of electric signal.

Answer (score 0):

On = 1

Off = 0

01100001 = 97

97 in ascii is "a"

That's how binary works. You can make everything with binary.

Comment: "how the letters and numbers exist in the first place in the CPU" thats was my question, u didn't answer that. On and OFF is not always 1 and 0, how exactly it is defined in the cpu!?